# objective-c why a .mm file is considered a int* type?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++

I am trying to create a weak reference of a .mm class... the problem is the file even though code-wise its a NSObject class it considers it as a int* type. If I change the file back to .m though it accepts it as a Obj-c class but the code stops working because of cocos2d requirement of files being .mm

```
//Game Logic is actually NSObject meaning obj-c class.
@interface GameLogic : NSObject 


//However here I get the error like the file is type int*
@property (weak,nonatomic)GameLogic * __weak gameLogicWeak;
```

Those are the 2 msgs I get.

```
Property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type

'__weak' only applies to Objective-C object or block pointer types; type here is 'int *'
```

Anyone has any idea what can I do to overcome this problem?
I know there exists many solutions, one of them would be just not create that weak link, use delegate, or well many other possible solutions.

But this solution was a cleaner one that I came up with which makes ARC come in handy with the memory clean up.

Any suggestions? Workarounds? Solutions? anyone has come with this problem?

====

I get the following message when @class GameLogic is added in .h and #import in the .m respectively.  This message is generated in a location where I am using the weak reference.

```
Receiver type 'GameLogic' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `[c++]`?

Comment: because a .mm file is compiled as c++, and was suggested by StackOverFlow and I accepted it because I thought it was logical. Take note that is also tagged as objc, and Cocos2d.

Comment: A .mm file is compiled as objective-c++.

Comment: ahh yeah I don't know, I was not able to create that tag... lack of 1,500 reputation. And well it was not suggested to me. But thanks for the edit.

Comment: I used a pre-existing tag.

Comment: I just tried a brief test and I can't reproduce this problem. I think there is some missing information about your situation. Is it possible that `GameLogic` is declared more than once?

Comment: I've never heard of creating a weak reference to a .mm file before.  Is this a new iOS feature?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm pretty sure he means reference to an Objective-C object.

Comment: Is `__weak` legal in that position in a property declaration?

Comment: dont worry about semantics and syntax... worry about the issue. And yes its validated. I do it to organize correctly my files and documentation. But its not necessary if @propery(weak) is already written.

Comment: I'm wondering if the Objective-C preprocessor doesn't generate the instance field declaration (for a weak property) by taking `GameLogic * __weak gameLogicWeak`, inserting `__weak` in it, and coming up with `GameLogic * __weak __weak gameLogicWeak`, which will look a lot like declaring the variable `__weak`, and will confuse the heck out of the C compiler.

Comment: No, I already tested it, I believe it sticks with the second statement the __weak ...but if you write.     `@property(weak) * __strong gamelogicWeak:` 
You get this msg: 

     `Weak property 'gameLogicWeak' may not also be declared __strong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do

```
#import "GameLogic.h"
```

in the header where you added the property? You can also add

```
@class GameLogic;
```

but not

```
class GameLogic;
```

because that would make it a forward reference to a C++ class. Also double-check that you don't actually have a C++ class of the same name.

And is that header file's implementation also .mm? Because it has to be if GameLogic allows direct access (property or return value) to a C++ class.

Comment: yes indeed I tried that. Because I have tried other classes like that before.
The following message is the one i receive.
- Receiver type 'GameLogic' for instance message is a forward declaration

Comment: didn't notice the header part what you said... So usually its at the .m that I need to add the #import... but since its C++ involved too, I need to add that same #import at the .h, very very interesting. Thanks you solved my problem pal.

Comment: Just one question for you @LearnCocos2D what is the difference between `class GameLogic;` and `@class GameLogic;`

Comment: class is the forward declaration of C++ denoting a C++ class, @class is the Objective-C pendant of forward declaration of an Objective-C class. For C++ classes you would use 'class' and for Objective-C classes you'd use '@class'.

Comment: Also, when you use a class object (C++ or Objective-C) in another header file you always have to either #import the class' header or use the class/@class keyword. Otherwise the compiler sees the name of the class as an undefined type, and by definition undefined types are regarded as 'int' (hence the "type here is int*" part).

Comment: but a .mm file its a objective-c++ type, so thats why I didnt notice that error, and didn't know how the error works(being undefined and undefined being regarded as int*).

Thanks, very well elaborated.